# Classifying an unknown class in LIbsvm

Tags: svm, libsvm

I have a dataset (2598), in which 108 instances belong to Class 1 and 87 belong to Class 2 , I need to classify all the rest instance in the dataset either as Class1 or 2 or Donot belong to this classification. Is it possible to do it using Libsvm , Since i am training the dataset using Class1 and Class2 and i need to find which dont belong to both of the classes.

Do help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiclass classification and train the 'rest' as class '3'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the number of class3 is too low

class 1 : 129
class 2: 239
class 3: 30

How to define weights for these in libsvm , i used multi_class_learn as referred in libsvm but there i could not assign weight and prediction went too low ..

Is there any other packages where i can do multiclass svm quite easier?? with weights